# Transforming coordinates from Swiss reference system LV95 to WGS84 using R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, wgs84

[image]

When I transform coordinates from LV95 to WGS84 using the R function `spTransform`, the resulting WGS84 coordinates are approx. 170 m off in direction North-East, i.e. they are incorrect.

Here is my code example:

```
library(rgdal)
```

conversion function:

```
myConvert_LV95_to_WGS84 = function(myCoords_LV95) {
    df = data.frame(myCoords_LV95)
    coordinates(df) = ~ X1 + X2
    df@proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:2056")
    myCoords_WGS84 = spTransform(df, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
    myCoords_WGS84@coords
}
```

Input sample LV95 coordinates:

```
coords_LV95 = matrix(
    c(2726201,1202028,
      2726148,1202001,
      2726148,1201995),
      nrow=3,
      ncol=2,
      byrow = TRUE
)

coords_WGS84 = myConvert_LV95_to_WGS84(coords_LV95)
```

Resulting WGS84 coordinates, which are incorrect:

```
coords_WGS84
        X1       X2
1 9.097946 46.95864
2 9.097242 46.95841
3 9.097241 46.95836
```

The correct WGS84 coordinates would be
(calculated from swisstopo's approximation formula):

```
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 9.096741 46.95733
[2,] 9.096037 46.95710
[3,] 9.096035 46.95704
```

The prj-file for the input coordinates:

```
> PROJCS["CH1903+_LV95",GEOGCS["GCS_CH1903+",DATUM["D_CH1903+",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",2600000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",1200000.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Azimuth",90.0],PARAMETER["Longitude_Of_Center",7.439583333333333],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Center",46.95240555555556],UNIT["Meter",1.0]],VERTCS["LN_1902",VDATUM["Landesnivellement_1902"],PARAMETER["Vertical_Shift",0.0],PARAMETER["Direction",1.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your correct output examples are three times the same values. Transforming your LV95 coordinates example, I get three slightly different vlaues (last 3 digits), see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMS4f.png - your problem might be due to a rounding error?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply and hints! I added the correct WGS84 coordinates above (sorry for that). I also added a screen shot, showing the distance between the correct (green) and wrong (red) lines (approx. 170m), quite big for a rounding error.

Comment: Question: your results are quite precise. Did you produce them with my R-code above or did you use your own transformation utility? Thank you!

Comment: I used QGIS for transformation

Comment: thank you! i need to fix in R ...

Comment: This smells like a datum conversion issue, but I am not familiar with R, so I can't say for sure. I notice that the [spTransform docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgdal/versions/1.5-23/topics/spTransform-methods) mention that the behaviour w.r.t. datums has changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint! The changed behaviour of spTransform is exactly the source of my problem. I ran an older example again, which originally returned correct coordinates, and now results in coordinates which are out by some 170 m. I did not yet find out, how to set the proj4string correctly...

Comment: I get your "correct" values with your code. what version of PROJ are you using? it should say when you do `library(rgdal)`. For me: `Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020, [PJ_VERSION: 631]`

Comment: Thank you for trying with my code and your input! My rgdal version is newer than yours: Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 7.2.1, January 1st, 2021, [PJ_VERSION: 721]. This seems to confirm the previous comments that the new version of rgdal (spTransform) shows a different behaviour. My open question is, how to properly set the (proj4string) parameters for correct results?